# menu items do not start correct activity

Tags: java, android, menu, settings

I have a menu with 3 items and each has an activity to start when it is clicked: my main.xml file looks like this:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/menuReport"
        android:title="Report an issue"
        />
<item
        android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
        android:title="About"
        />
<item
        android:id="@+id/menuSettings"
        android:title="Settings"
        />
```

and in my main activity i have this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    //respond to menu item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuReport:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, reportIssue.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.menuAbout:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, about.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.menuSettings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
            return true;
    }
    return true;
   }}
```

However selecting either of the first two menu choices "Report an issue" and "about" do nothing, but selecting "Settings" starts the activity under "Report an issue". The other menu items did work until i added settings back in and im not sure what caused this

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Comment: I tried that about 3 times and still didn't do the trick

Comment: Have you restarted your editor since? I don't see any way for this code to produce those results.

Comment: i switched from android studio to inetlij and then it worked fine. must be an android studio issue

Comment: I wouldn't trust AS right now. Its a preview release so there will be a lot of bugs so it isn't recommended unless you have a high ability in Android programming so you can know when the bugs are the code and when it is likely the IDE. Glad you got it working